# Serializing generics into JSON without converting the generic field into a String?

Tags: java, json, generics, serialization

I have a DTO that will send back an object of a generic type. Here's an example:

```
public class ATestDTO<E> implements Serializable {
    private E generic;

    public E getGeneric() {
        return generic;
    }

    public void setGeneric( E generic ) {
        this.generic = generic;
    }
}
```

If E is say, a Long, it will output it as a String isntead of as a number. I would want it to output as a number.

```
ATestDTO<Long> dto = new ATestDTO();
dto.setGeneric(1l);

//Outputs:
{
  "generic": "1"
}

//Desired:
{
  "generic": 1
}
```

Funnily enough, if the field is a `List<E>`, it'll output numbers instead of strings in the List, so I know it's possible.

**Attempts at fixing:**

-I tried casting it by passing in the class, but it still output a string

Comment: How are you serializing to JSON?

Comment: We are using Johnzon.